# Django - Proper Way To Use LoginView

Tags: python, django, authentication, view

I've read that function-based login is deprecated as of 1.11, but also that LoginView is not available as of Django version 1.9. What's the current way to set up a login URL if we aren't supposed to do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
```

and we can't do this?

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
```

(the latter yields a `No name 'LoginView' in module 'django.contrib.auth.views'` message)

Comment: If you're using the Django docs then make sure that you are using the version that matches your Django version. For example, here are the authentication views docs for [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) and [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views). As an aside, Django 1.9 is end of life and no longer receives security updates. You should upgrade to Django 1.10 or ideally 1.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated means, generally, that  something is acknowledged but discouraged. In the future releases, the functionality is going to be definitely removed though.

Deprecation means that although something is available or allowed, it is not recommended or that, in the case where something must be used, to say it is deprecated means that its failings are recognized.

This doesn't mean we need to stop doing this. As above said, it is recommended not to do this. Still the way for login hasn't changed, but django gives us a warning that its about to be changed. If you have to do a login view, you dont have any other choice right now, but to use the function.

Hopefully, LoginView would be available in the coming releases.

Comment: Yes, that is what I m saying too. definitely gonna be removed. but right now, its available and allowed. isn't that right?